# Write a header to a log with log4php

Tags: php, log4php

I have semi-colon separated values logged to a csv file using log4php. 
I wanted to write a header in first line. How this can be done?

**Example**

message id, file name, start time, end time, status
MSGID1000;SAMPLE.TXT;01:05:55;07:08:44;OK
MSGID1000;SAMPLE.TXT;01:05:55;07:08:44;NOK

I do this

```
csvLogger = Logger::getRootLogger();
csvLogger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::toLevel(LoggerLevel::DEBUG));
csvLogger->removeAllAppenders();

$appender = new LoggerAppenderFile("csvLogAppender");
$appender->setFile("LogMessage.csv");
$appender->setAppend(false);   

csvLogger->addAppender($appender);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to extend `LoggerLayoutPattern` and override the `getHeader()` method.

```
class csvLoggerLayoutPattern extends LoggerLayoutPattern {
    public function getHeader() {
        return "message id, file name, start time, end time, status\n";
    }
}

csvLogger = Logger::getRootLogger();
csvLogger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::toLevel(LoggerLevel::DEBUG));
csvLogger->removeAllAppenders();

$appender = new LoggerAppenderFile("csvLogAppender");
$appender->setFile("LogMessage.csv");
$appender->setAppend(false);

$appenderlayout = new csvLoggerLayoutPattern();
$appenderlayout->activateOptions();
$appender->setLayout($appenderlayout);

csvLogger->addAppender($appender);
```